# tikzpicture - Runaway argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I am new to this forum, and I have a question regarding plotting a line graph in Latex. I am hoping some of you might have experience solving this issue. Thanks a lot!

I tried to plot a graph with the below code, however, i received the following error message:

```
"Runaway argument?
1]\else \expandafter \expandafter \csname pgfflt@1Y1.1e1]\endcsname \fi \ETC.
File ended while scanning use of \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat.
<inserted text>"
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=13cm,compat=1.14}
\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace*{2em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Aggregate share 1985 - 2014}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=Year,
ylabel={share in \%},
xmin=1985, xmax=2014,
ymin=5, ymax=15,
xtick={1985,1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2014},
ytick={5,7,9,11,13,15},
legend pos=north west,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[color=blue,]
plot coordinates {
(1985, 8)
(1988, 7.5)
(1991, 10.4)
(1994, 7.8)
(1997, 7.5)
(2000, 7.8)
(2003, 8.8)
(2006, 9.3)
(2009, 10.4)
(2012, 11)
(2014, 11,9)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your last data point is supposed to be 11.9?

Comment: Not the best error message, but `...readlowlevelfloat` should be a hint...

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
(2014, 11.9)
```

not

```
(2014, 11,9)
```

as the last coordinate.